# JmsMessagingTemplate is message converter broken?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

I was trying to use a `JmsMessagingTemplate` with a `JmsTemplate` that has a `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter` but the problem is that navigating up on the `JmsMessagingTemplate` to `org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate` where the converter used is an implementation of `org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter` which doesn't seem compatible with `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter`.

Is this broken or I'm trying to do something wrong here?

Comment: Messaging is a higher abstraction using different classes so the classes you are using are, indeed, not compatible.

Comment: After a while I found out that org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate have a org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.MessagingMessageCreator where the real conversion happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm wrapping around a jmsMessagingTemplate I had to set the converter explicitly like this:

```
public DelegatingJmsMessagingTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsMessagingTemplate = new JmsMessagingTemplate(jmsTemplate);
    final var messagingMessageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter(jmsTemplate.getMessageConverter());
    this.jmsMessagingTemplate.setJmsMessageConverter(messagingMessageConverter); //seems to do the trick
    this.jmsMessagingTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestinationName());
}
```

now both publisher and subscriber convert the message accordingly.

As I mention in a comment, I found out that org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate have a org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate.MessagingMessageCreator where the real conversion happens.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added your configuration code. So assuming that you have not added bean for message converter. Please find below code snippet for the configuration, hope that will resolve the problem.

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return objectMapper;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(url);
    connectionFactory.setUserName(user);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    return connectionFactory;
}
```